# Yosemite login freeze after sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake, performance

I've seen several threads to this effect, but none that have resolved my issues with logging in successfully after sleep for a relatively long time, or after working with an external monitor, then sleeping and waking/logging in...in these cases I'm frozen and have to force shutdown, then reboot.

I'm on Yosemite 10.10.2 (was same with 10.10.1) on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013; 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7 processor; 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 memory) with last Console log entry below (quite a few minutes prior to attempted wake).

I don't see errors at time of freeze; next thing is my reboot.

```
Jan 29 19:40:11 JDPRubato kernel[0]: PM response took 3142 ms (31, powerd)
Jan 29 19:40:11 JDPRubato kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000280
Jan 29 19:40:11 JDPRubato kernel[0]: [0x6c4c826000, 0xfff0000]
Jan 29 19:40:11 JDPRubato kernel[0]: [0x12d281000, 0x9010000]
Jan 29 19:40:11 JDPRubato kernel[0]: [0x1cda1e000, 0xd21e000]
Jan 29 19:40:11 JDPRubato kernel[0]: [0x66eb9000, 0xbde2000]
Jan 29 19:40:11 JDPRubato kernel[0]: [0x7409eb0000, 0xb71a000]
Jan 29 19:40:11 JDPRubato kernel[0]: [0x22361d000, 0x28e6000]
Jan 29 19:40:11 JDPRubato kernel[0]: [0x0, 0x0]
Jan 29 19:40:11 JDPRubato kernel[0]: ARPT: 8545.920881: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Sleep 
Jan 29 19:40:11 JDPRubato kernel[0]: ARPT: 8545.920884: wl0: powerChange: *** BONJOUR/MDNS OFFLOADS ARE NOT RUNNING.
Jan 29 19:40:11 JDPRubato kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
```

---

Oops, was hoping to enter most recent log following no sharing/VPN/backup test,  but >max allowable characters per body post...deleting previous logs to free up room...see comment at current bottom of thread.

```
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: Wake reason: RTC (Alarm)
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: RTC: SleepService 2015/2/1 19:05:58, sleep 2015/2/1 17:51:28
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::wakeEventHandlerThread
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: Previous sleep cause: 5
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltNHIType2::prePCIWake - power up complete - took 1 us
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff8036c88800>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 11 unplug = 0
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff8036c88800>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 12 unplug = 0
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: TBT W (2): 0x0040 [x]
2/1/15 11:05:58.180 discoveryd[54]: Basic Bonjour stop listening on awdl0
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 90:72:40:1d:6c:d5
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: en0: channel changed to 40,80
2/1/15 11:05:58.243 sharingd[235]: 11:05:58.242 : SDStatusMonitor::kStatusWirelessPowerChanged
2/1/15 11:05:58.247 acvpnagent[22]: Function: GetPrimaryInterfaceIndex File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 422 Unable to get global IPv6 information from system configuration.
2/1/15 11:05:58.248 acvpnagent[22]: Function: determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1769 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::FindDefaultRouteInterface Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
2/1/15 11:05:58.248 acvpnagent[22]: Function: updatePotentialPublicAddresses File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1914 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
2/1/15 11:05:58.256 acvpnagent[22]: Function: internalWriteSocket File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC/UdpTcpTransports_unix.cpp Line: 299 Invoked Function: ::send Return Code: 50 (0x00000032) Description: unknown 
2/1/15 11:05:58.256 acvpnagent[22]: Function: writeSocket File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC/SocketTransport.cpp Line: 1181 Invoked Function: CSocketTransport::internalWriteSocket Return Code: -31588341 (0xFE1E000B) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_WRITE 
2/1/15 11:05:58.256 acvpnagent[22]: Function: performDNSRequest File: ../../vpn/Common/IP/DNSRequest.cpp Line: 574 Invoked Function: CUdpTransport::writeSocket Return Code: -31588341 (0xFE1E000B) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_WRITE DNS server 10.0.1.1
2/1/15 11:05:58.256 acvpnagent[22]: Function: Query File: ../../vpn/Common/IP/DNSRequest.cpp Line: 439 Invoked Function: CDNSRequest::performDNSRequest Return Code: -31588341 (0xFE1E000B) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_WRITE 
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff8036c88800>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 1 unplug = 0
2/1/15 11:05:58.256 acvpnagent[22]: Function: testDnsAccess File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 897 Invoked Function: DNSRequest::Query Return Code: -31588341 (0xFE1E000B) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_WRITE 
2/1/15 11:05:58.256 acvpnagent[22]: Function: testNetwork File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 739 Invoked Function: CNetEnvironment::testDnsAccess Return Code: -31588341 (0xFE1E000B) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_WRITE 
2/1/15 11:05:58.256 acvpnagent[22]: Function: TestNetEnv File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 230 Invoked Function: CNetEnvironment::testNetwork Return Code: -31588341 (0xFE1E000B) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_WRITE 
2/1/15 11:05:58.256 acvpnagent[22]: Function: TestNetEnv File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 370 No DNS connectivity. Retesting connectivity to the secure gateway in 5 seconds.
2/1/15 11:05:58.256 acvpnagent[22]: Current network state: No DNS connectivity
2/1/15 11:05:58.259 acvpnagent[22]: Function: GetPrimaryInterfaceIndex File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 422 Unable to get global IPv6 information from system configuration.
2/1/15 11:05:58.259 acvpnagent[22]: Function: determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1769 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::FindDefaultRouteInterface Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
2/1/15 11:05:58.259 acvpnagent[22]: Function: updatePotentialPublicAddresses File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1914 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::checkStatus - received Status Packet, Payload 2: device was reinitialized
2/1/15 11:05:58.314 hidd[74]: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltGenericHAL::earlyWake - complete - took 575 milliseconds
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration begin ]
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration end, bridges 15, devices 15 ]
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration begin ]
2/1/15 11:05:58.000 kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration end, bridges 15, devices 15 ]
2/1/15 11:05:59.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 12945.980675: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Wake - Full Wake/ Dark Wake / Maintenance wake
2/1/15 11:05:59.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
2/1/15 11:05:59.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::wakeEventHandlerThread
2/1/15 11:05:59.000 kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 90:72:40:1d:6c:d5
2/1/15 11:05:59.000 kernel[0]: en0: channel changed to 40,80
2/1/15 11:05:59.069 sharingd[235]: 11:05:59.068 : SDStatusMonitor::kStatusWirelessPowerChanged
2/1/15 11:05:59.000 kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 90:72:40:1d:6c:d5
2/1/15 11:05:59.000 kernel[0]: en0: channel changed to 40,80
2/1/15 11:05:59.089 sharingd[235]: 11:05:59.088 : SDStatusMonitor::kStatusWirelessPowerChanged
2/1/15 11:05:59.000 kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Up on awdl0
2/1/15 11:05:59.328 acvpnagent[22]: A new network interface has been detected.
2/1/15 11:05:59.328 acvpnagent[22]: Function: logInterfaces File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/Routing/InterfaceRouteMonitorCommon.cpp Line: 477 IP Address Interface List: FE80:0:0:0:BAE8:56FF:FE46:25E2 10.0.1.5 FE80:0:0:0:809F:2DFF:FEAC:8A65 FE80:0:0:0:6A5B:35FF:FE93:FDE5 10.0.1.3 
2/1/15 11:05:59.329 acvpnagent[22]: Function: netInterfaceNoticeCategoryHandler File: ../../vpn/Agent/MainThread.cpp Line: 7388 Network Interface change detected, refreshing physical MAC addresses
2/1/15 11:06:01.483 discoveryd[54]: AwdlD2d AwdlD2dStartAdvertisingPair: 'jdprubato' Advertising service started
2/1/15 11:06:01.484 discoveryd[54]: AwdlD2d AwdlD2dStartAdvertisingPair: 'jdprubato' Advertising service started
2/1/15 11:06:01.485 discoveryd[54]: AwdlD2d AwdlD2dStartAdvertisingPair: '56a8caefffd2f90800000000000008efip6arpa' Advertising service started
2/1/15 11:06:03.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::handleWakeEvent_gated
2/1/15 11:06:04.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::handleWakeEvent_gated
2/1/15 11:06:04.458 acvpnagent[22]: Function: GetPrimaryInterfaceIndex File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 422 Unable to get global IPv6 information from system configuration.
2/1/15 11:06:04.459 acvpnagent[22]: Function: determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1769 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::FindDefaultRouteInterface Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
2/1/15 11:06:04.459 acvpnagent[22]: Function: updatePotentialPublicAddresses File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1914 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
2/1/15 11:06:07.000 kernel[0]: Ethernet [AppleBCM5701Ethernet]: Link up on en3, 1-Gigabit, Full-duplex, Symmetric flow-control, EEE enabled, Debug [796d,0301,0de1,0300,cde1,3c00]
2/1/15 11:06:07.743 acvpnagent[22]: Function: logProbeFailure File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1417 The HTTPS probe to 149.175.254.20 resulted in a redirect.
2/1/15 11:06:12.000 kernel[0]: kauth external resolver timed out (1 timeout(s) of 60 seconds).
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: PM response took 28018 ms (28, powerd)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: full wake request (reason 1) 29335 ms
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000320
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
2/1/15 11:06:27.335 watchdogd[204]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000320 msg=0x0
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: NVRM: 0x702a called in D3
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
2/1/15 11:06:27.743 WindowServer[130]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [12974693028097]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake
2/1/15 11:06:27.748 WindowServer[130]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Deferring.
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000300
2/1/15 11:06:27.750 watchdogd[204]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000300 msg=0x0
2/1/15 11:06:27.750 coreaudiod[226]: 2015-02-01 11:06:27.749938 AM [AirPlay] Power: SystemHasPoweredOn
2/1/15 11:06:27.751 sharingd[235]: 11:06:27.750 : Starting AirDrop server for user 1878966864 on wake
2/1/15 11:06:27.750 coreaudiod[226]: 2015-02-01 11:06:27.750486 AM [AirPlay] BTLE client starting to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
2/1/15 11:06:27.752 coreaudiod[226]: 2015-02-01 11:06:27.751641 AM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopping to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
2/1/15 11:06:27.752 coreaudiod[226]: 2015-02-01 11:06:27.751840 AM [AirPlay] BTLE client starting to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
2/1/15 11:06:27.753 coreaudiod[226]: 2015-02-01 11:06:27.752590 AM [AirPlay] BTLE client started to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
2/1/15 11:06:27.753 coreaudiod[226]: 2015-02-01 11:06:27.752772 AM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopped to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
2/1/15 11:06:27.753 coreaudiod[226]: 2015-02-01 11:06:27.752937 AM [AirPlay] BTLE client started to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.761 discoveryd[54]: None ClientIPC DNSServiceRemoveRecord: registrationId is 0 Client[netbiosd(187)]
2/1/15 11:06:27.763 discoveryd[54]: None ClientIPC DNSServiceRemoveRecord: registrationId is 0 Client[netbiosd(187)]
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.764 discoveryd[54]: None ClientIPC DNSServiceRemoveRecord: registrationId is 0 Client[netbiosd(187)]
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:27.765 discoveryd[54]: None ClientIPC DNSServiceRemoveRecord: registrationId is 0 Client[netbiosd(187)]
2/1/15 11:06:27.776 periodic-wrapper[849]: Running daily periodic task.
2/1/15 11:06:27.858 identityservicesd[239]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fe7521328b0>: notification observer: com.apple.iChat   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fe752027f20 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbDisabledNotification}
2/1/15 11:06:28.109 CalendarAgent[241]: CalDAV account refresh completed
com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.sleepservices.icalData
com.apple.message.signature: CalDAV account refresh statistics
com.apple.message.result: noop
com.apple.message.value: 0
com.apple.message.value2: 0
com.apple.message.value3: 0
com.apple.message.uuid: B311963E-C72E-4DB7-8EFD-06483E547B68
com.apple.message.uuid2: 0A344B22-9AE8-4D68-9EC4-11DDB7615039
com.apple.message.wake_state: 0
SenderMachUUID: 4341D30B-26F9-36C2-A56B-830AC643268D

2/1/15 11:06:28.444 CalendarAgent[241]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.coredav] [Refusing to parse response to PROPPATCH because of content-type: [text/html; charset=UTF-8].]
2/1/15 11:06:28.485 CalendarAgent[241]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.coredav] [Refusing to parse response to PROPPATCH because of content-type: [text/html; charset=UTF-8].]
2/1/15 11:06:28.505 CalendarAgent[241]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.coredav] [Refusing to parse response to PROPPATCH because of content-type: [text/html; charset=UTF-8].]
2/1/15 11:06:28.539 CalendarAgent[241]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.coredav] [Refusing to parse response to PROPPATCH because of content-type: [text/html; charset=UTF-8].]
2/1/15 11:06:28.551 CalendarAgent[241]: CalDAV account refresh completed
com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.sleepservices.icalData
com.apple.message.signature: CalDAV account refresh statistics
com.apple.message.result: noop
com.apple.message.value: 0
com.apple.message.value2: 0
com.apple.message.value3: 0
com.apple.message.uuid: B311963E-C72E-4DB7-8EFD-06483E547B68
com.apple.message.uuid2: 0A344B22-9AE8-4D68-9EC4-11DDB7615039
com.apple.message.wake_state: 0
SenderMachUUID: 4341D30B-26F9-36C2-A56B-830AC643268D

2/1/15 11:06:29.070 CalendarAgent[241]: CalDAV account refresh completed
com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.sleepservices.icalData
com.apple.message.signature: CalDAV account refresh statistics
com.apple.message.result: noop
com.apple.message.value: 0
com.apple.message.value2: 0
com.apple.message.value3: 0
com.apple.message.uuid: B311963E-C72E-4DB7-8EFD-06483E547B68
com.apple.message.uuid2: 0A344B22-9AE8-4D68-9EC4-11DDB7615039
com.apple.message.wake_state: 0
SenderMachUUID: 4341D30B-26F9-36C2-A56B-830AC643268D

2/1/15 11:06:31.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:31.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:31.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:31.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:31.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:31.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:31.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:31.000 kernel[0]: [SendRawHCICommand] ### ERROR: EnqueueRequestForController failed (err=e00002d8)
2/1/15 11:06:32.766 blued[63]: Logging disabled
2/1/15 11:06:37.919 identityservicesd[239]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fe7521328b0>:    NC Disabled: NO
2/1/15 11:06:42.993 identityservicesd[239]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fe7521328b0>:   DND Enabled: NO
2/1/15 11:06:42.993 identityservicesd[239]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fe7521328b0>: Updating enabled: YES   (Topics: (
    "com.apple.private.alloy.icloudpairing",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.encryption",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.activity",
    "com.apple.ess",
    "com.apple.private.ids",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.phonecontinuity",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.activity.public",
    "com.apple.madrid",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.auth",
    "com.apple.private.ac",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.idsremoteurlconnection",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.sms",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.screensharing",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.maps",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.callhistorysync",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.tethering"
))
2/1/15 11:06:42.994 identityservicesd[239]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fe75221e9d0>: notification observer: com.apple.iChat   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fe7521cc8f0 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbDisabledNotification}
2/1/15 11:06:50.661 imagent[278]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fcfbb305630>: notification observer: com.apple.FaceTime   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fcfbb22e5e0 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbDisabledNotification}
2/1/15 11:06:55.185 identityservicesd[239]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fe75221e9d0>:    NC Disabled: NO
2/1/15 11:06:56.197 identityservicesd[239]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fe75221e9d0>:   DND Enabled: NO
2/1/15 11:06:56.197 identityservicesd[239]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fe75221e9d0>: Updating enabled: YES   (Topics: (
    "com.apple.madrid"
))
2/1/15 11:06:56.198 imagent[278]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fcfbb305630>:    NC Disabled: NO
2/1/15 11:06:57.209 imagent[278]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fcfbb305630>:   DND Enabled: NO
2/1/15 11:06:57.209 imagent[278]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fcfbb305630>: Updating enabled: YES   (Topics: (
    "com.apple.ess",
    "com.apple.private.ac"
))
```

Comment: can we have more of that log, from the wake reason + 50 lines

Comment: So, the next set of lines would simply be the reboot...would there be errors mentioned during reboot? I mostly just see processes underway etc. Let me know and I can upload those lines as well. Basically, no special lines appear upon wake.

Comment: find "wake reason" in (show all) and copy lines after that, it should be many - (lots of activity), like Airport, Thunderbolt, lots of kernels, hibernate image ect...

Comment: I do see wake reason at other times, but apparently only at times where it successfully woke/allowed login. The ones I can currently find are added to my initial post (too long for here).

Comment: waking up is a process consisting of many steps. I did not need you to show me all your wake up, but show what comes after it, it is not possible not to have anything, and it is not correct that it will only show something upon successful completion of the wake.

Comment: Okay, well, my log basically stopped with the first set of lines reported above, then started again with the reboot I did after attempted wake from sleep. There were no lines relating to wake reason. I'll wait for the freeze after sleep again, and return to this thread and provide further details.

Comment: Aha, got a log this time upon unsuccessful wake...will append it above...Jim P.

Comment: Do this one at the time and test- Disable Sharing, Disable VPN, Disable Back up. You also have one Crash Report: 1/31/15 19:47:04.864 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.ReportCrash.Root[1368]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.ReportCrash.DirectoryService

Comment: Okay, confirmed Sharing is off, not using VPN, disabled backup. Same symptoms upon wake from extended sleep. Log file appended above (note my manual wake at/around 11:06.31, not original wake it notes). Sorry, I'm not sure how to access crash reports. Thanks...Jim P.

Comment: sorry, your VPN is still running causing problems, process name "acvpnagent"