# Now Yosemite login slow after sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake

See my former thread [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169668/yosemite-login-freeze-after-sleep?noredirect=1#comment199734_169668). Now when I wake from sleep, login seems to work, but it takes perhaps 15-30 seconds to restore to functional state. Log below, starting from wake_reason at 09:35:49 through last log msg at 09:36:18 prior to functionality being restored. (See bottom, where more recent wake log issues listed; now wake takes less time, but still much more than with Mavericks.) Sure appreciate anyone's input...Jim P.

```
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: Wake reason: EC.LidOpen (User)
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000320
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::wakeEventHandlerThread
2/5/15 09:35:49.001 watchdogd[204]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000320 msg=0x0
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: Previous sleep cause: 5
2/5/15 09:35:49.004 discoveryd[1932]: Basic DNSResolver UDNSServer:: PowerState is Wakeup
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltNHIType2::prePCIWake - power up complete - took 1 us
2/5/15 09:35:49.013 com.apple.backupd-helper[45]: Attempt to use XPC with a MachService that has HideUntilCheckIn set. This will result in unpredictable behavior: com.apple.backupd.status.xpc
2/5/15 09:35:49.115 discoveryd[1932]: Basic Bonjour stop listening on awdl0
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: TBT W (2): 0x0040 [x]
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff8024d22800>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 11 unplug = 0
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff8024d22800>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 12 unplug = 0
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff8024d22800>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 1 unplug = 0
2/5/15 09:35:49.147 Evernote[2987]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 17 connectx to 204.154.94.81:443@0 failed: Network is down
2/5/15 09:35:49.221 Evernote[2987]: tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete 19 connectx to 204.154.94.81:443@0 failed: Network is down
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 90:72:40:1d:6c:d5
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: en0: channel changed to 40,80
2/5/15 09:35:49.242 sharingd[236]: 09:35:49.241 : SDStatusMonitor::kStatusWirelessPowerChanged
2/5/15 09:35:49.248 acvpnagent[22]: Function: GetPrimaryInterfaceIndex File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 422 Unable to get global IPv6 information from system configuration.
2/5/15 09:35:49.249 acvpnagent[22]: Function: determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1769 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::FindDefaultRouteInterface Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
2/5/15 09:35:49.249 acvpnagent[22]: Function: updatePotentialPublicAddresses File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1914 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 90:72:40:1d:6c:d5
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: en0: channel changed to 40,80
2/5/15 09:35:49.255 sharingd[236]: 09:35:49.254 : SDStatusMonitor::kStatusWirelessPowerChanged
2/5/15 09:35:49.259 acvpnagent[22]: Function: internalWriteSocket File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC/UdpTcpTransports_unix.cpp Line: 299 Invoked Function: ::send Return Code: 50 (0x00000032) Description: unknown 
2/5/15 09:35:49.259 acvpnagent[22]: Function: writeSocket File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC/SocketTransport.cpp Line: 1181 Invoked Function: CSocketTransport::internalWriteSocket Return Code: -31588341 (0xFE1E000B) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_WRITE 
2/5/15 09:35:49.259 acvpnagent[22]: Function: performDNSRequest File: ../../vpn/Common/IP/DNSRequest.cpp Line: 574 Invoked Function: CUdpTransport::writeSocket Return Code: -31588341 (0xFE1E000B) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_WRITE DNS server 10.0.1.1
2/5/15 09:35:49.259 acvpnagent[22]: Function: Query File: ../../vpn/Common/IP/DNSRequest.cpp Line: 439 Invoked Function: CDNSRequest::performDNSRequest Return Code: -31588341 (0xFE1E000B) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_WRITE 
2/5/15 09:35:49.260 acvpnagent[22]: Function: testDnsAccess File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 897 Invoked Function: DNSRequest::Query Return Code: -31588341 (0xFE1E000B) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_WRITE 
2/5/15 09:35:49.260 acvpnagent[22]: Function: testNetwork File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 739 Invoked Function: CNetEnvironment::testDnsAccess Return Code: -31588341 (0xFE1E000B) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_WRITE 
2/5/15 09:35:49.260 acvpnagent[22]: Function: TestNetEnv File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 230 Invoked Function: CNetEnvironment::testNetwork Return Code: -31588341 (0xFE1E000B) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_WRITE 
2/5/15 09:35:49.260 acvpnagent[22]: Function: TestNetEnv File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 370 No DNS connectivity. Retesting connectivity to the secure gateway in 5 seconds.
2/5/15 09:35:49.260 acvpnagent[22]: Current network state: No DNS connectivity
2/5/15 09:35:49.264 acvpnagent[22]: Function: GetPrimaryInterfaceIndex File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 422 Unable to get global IPv6 information from system configuration.
2/5/15 09:35:49.265 acvpnagent[22]: Function: determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1769 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::FindDefaultRouteInterface Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
2/5/15 09:35:49.265 acvpnagent[22]: Function: updatePotentialPublicAddresses File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1914 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::checkStatus - received Status Packet, Payload 2: device was reinitialized
2/5/15 09:35:49.317 hidd[74]: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
2/5/15 09:35:49.317 discoveryd[1932]: Basic Bonjour,Warn Warning: IPv4 listener multicast send failed en3, 50
2/5/15 09:35:49.317 discoveryd[1932]: Basic Bonjour,Warn Warning: IPv6 listener multicast send failed en3, 50
2/5/15 09:35:49.318 discoveryd[1932]: Basic Bonjour,Warn Warning: IPv4 listener multicast send failed en3, 50
2/5/15 09:35:49.318 discoveryd[1932]: Basic Bonjour,Warn Warning: IPv6 listener multicast send failed en3, 50
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltGenericHAL::earlyWake - complete - took 439 milliseconds
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration begin ]
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration end, bridges 15, devices 15 ]
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration begin ]
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration end, bridges 15, devices 15 ]
2/5/15 09:35:49.571 discoveryd[1932]: Basic Bonjour,Warn Warning: IPv4 listener multicast send failed en3, 50
2/5/15 09:35:49.571 discoveryd[1932]: Basic Bonjour,Warn Warning: IPv6 listener multicast send failed en3, 50
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 58829.227575: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Wake - Full Wake/ Dark Wake / Maintenance wake
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::wakeEventHandlerThread
2/5/15 09:35:49.913 WindowServer[132]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [58829229524755]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake
2/5/15 09:35:49.913 WindowServer[132]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Reordering authw 0x7ffd3a9690f0(2004) (lock state: 3)
2/5/15 09:35:49.913 WindowServer[132]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: err 0x0
2/5/15 09:35:49.947 discoveryd[1932]: Basic DNSResolver UDNSServer:: PowerState is Wakeup
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000300
2/5/15 09:35:49.948 watchdogd[204]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000300 msg=0x0
2/5/15 09:35:49.948 coreaudiod[227]: 2015-02-05 09:35:49.948416 AM [AirPlay] Power: SystemHasPoweredOn
2/5/15 09:35:49.949 coreaudiod[227]: 2015-02-05 09:35:49.948531 AM [AirPlay] BTLE client starting to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
2/5/15 09:35:49.949 sharingd[236]: 09:35:49.948 : Starting AirDrop server for user 1878966864 on wake
2/5/15 09:35:49.949 coreaudiod[227]: 2015-02-05 09:35:49.949162 AM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopping to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
2/5/15 09:35:49.949 coreaudiod[227]: 2015-02-05 09:35:49.949296 AM [AirPlay] BTLE client starting to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
2/5/15 09:35:49.949 coreaudiod[227]: 2015-02-05 09:35:49.949464 AM [AirPlay] BTLE client started to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
2/5/15 09:35:49.950 coreaudiod[227]: 2015-02-05 09:35:49.950084 AM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopped to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
2/5/15 09:35:49.950 coreaudiod[227]: 2015-02-05 09:35:49.950189 AM [AirPlay] BTLE client started to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
2/5/15 09:35:49.957 discoveryd[1932]: None ClientIPC DNSServiceRemoveRecord: registrationId is 0 Client[netbiosd(1976)]
2/5/15 09:35:49.958 discoveryd[1932]: None ClientIPC DNSServiceRemoveRecord: registrationId is 0 Client[netbiosd(1976)]
2/5/15 09:35:49.958 discoveryd[1932]: None ClientIPC DNSServiceRemoveRecord: registrationId is 0 Client[netbiosd(1976)]
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 90:72:40:1d:6c:d5
2/5/15 09:35:49.000 kernel[0]: en0: channel changed to 40,80
2/5/15 09:35:49.971 sharingd[236]: 09:35:49.970 : SDStatusMonitor::kStatusWirelessPowerChanged
2/5/15 09:35:50.027 imagent[271]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7f8bcbe1eaa0>: notification observer: com.apple.FaceTime   notification: __CFNotification 0x7f8bcbc68780 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbDisabledNotification}
2/5/15 09:35:50.027 identityservicesd[243]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fce4a72d3c0>: notification observer: com.apple.iChat   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fce4a618830 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbDisabledNotification}
2/5/15 09:35:50.000 kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 90:72:40:1d:6c:d5
2/5/15 09:35:50.000 kernel[0]: en0: channel changed to 40,80
2/5/15 09:35:50.039 imagent[271]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7f8bcbe1eaa0>:    NC Disabled: NO
2/5/15 09:35:50.039 identityservicesd[243]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fce4a72d3c0>:    NC Disabled: NO
2/5/15 09:35:50.042 sharingd[236]: 09:35:50.042 : SDStatusMonitor::kStatusWirelessPowerChanged
2/5/15 09:35:50.054 imagent[271]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7f8bcbe1eaa0>:   DND Enabled: NO
2/5/15 09:35:50.054 identityservicesd[243]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fce4a72d3c0>:   DND Enabled: NO
2/5/15 09:35:50.054 imagent[271]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7f8bcbe1eaa0>: Updating enabled: YES   (Topics: (
    "com.apple.ess",
    "com.apple.private.ac"
))
2/5/15 09:35:50.054 identityservicesd[243]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fce4a72d3c0>: Updating enabled: YES   (Topics: (
    "com.apple.private.alloy.icloudpairing",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.encryption",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.activity",
    "com.apple.ess",
    "com.apple.private.ids",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.phonecontinuity",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.activity.public",
    "com.apple.madrid",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.auth",
    "com.apple.private.ac",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.idsremoteurlconnection",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.sms",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.screensharing",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.maps",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.callhistorysync",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.tethering"
))
2/5/15 09:35:50.055 identityservicesd[243]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fce4c23a720>: notification observer: com.apple.iChat   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fce4c327f50 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbDisabledNotification}
2/5/15 09:35:50.000 kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 90:72:40:1d:6c:d5
2/5/15 09:35:50.000 kernel[0]: en0: channel changed to 40,80
2/5/15 09:35:50.059 sharingd[236]: 09:35:50.059 : SDStatusMonitor::kStatusWirelessPowerChanged
2/5/15 09:35:50.060 identityservicesd[243]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fce4c23a720>:    NC Disabled: NO
2/5/15 09:35:50.064 identityservicesd[243]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fce4c23a720>:   DND Enabled: NO
2/5/15 09:35:50.064 identityservicesd[243]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fce4c23a720>: Updating enabled: YES   (Topics: (
    "com.apple.madrid"
))
2/5/15 09:35:50.202 storeassetd[357]: multibyte ASN1 identifiers are  not supported.
2/5/15 09:35:50.000 kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Up on awdl0
2/5/15 09:35:50.311 acvpnagent[22]: A new network interface has been detected.
2/5/15 09:35:50.311 acvpnagent[22]: Function: logInterfaces File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/Routing/InterfaceRouteMonitorCommon.cpp Line: 477 IP Address Interface List: FE80:0:0:0:BAE8:56FF:FE46:25E2 10.0.1.5 FE80:0:0:0:98D6:3EFF:FE57:EE56 FE80:0:0:0:6A5B:35FF:FE93:FDE5 10.0.1.3 
2/5/15 09:35:50.311 acvpnagent[22]: Function: netInterfaceNoticeCategoryHandler File: ../../vpn/Agent/MainThread.cpp Line: 7388 Network Interface change detected, refreshing physical MAC addresses
2/5/15 09:35:52.329 discoveryd[1932]: AwdlD2d AwdlD2dStartAdvertisingPair: 'jdprubato' Advertising service started
2/5/15 09:35:52.330 discoveryd[1932]: AwdlD2d AwdlD2dStartAdvertisingPair: 'jdprubato' Advertising service started
2/5/15 09:35:52.331 discoveryd[1932]: AwdlD2d AwdlD2dStartAdvertisingPair: '65ee75efffe36d8900000000000008efip6arpa' Advertising service started
2/5/15 09:35:54.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::handleWakeEvent_gated
2/5/15 09:35:54.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::handleWakeEvent_gated
2/5/15 09:35:55.383 acvpnagent[22]: Function: GetPrimaryInterfaceIndex File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 422 Unable to get global IPv6 information from system configuration.
2/5/15 09:35:55.384 acvpnagent[22]: Function: determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1769 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::FindDefaultRouteInterface Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
2/5/15 09:35:55.384 acvpnagent[22]: Function: updatePotentialPublicAddresses File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1914 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
2/5/15 09:35:58.000 kernel[0]: Ethernet [AppleBCM5701Ethernet]: Link up on en3, 1-Gigabit, Full-duplex, Symmetric flow-control, EEE enabled, Debug [796d,2301,0de1,0300,cde1,3c00]
2/5/15 09:35:58.678 acvpnagent[22]: Function: logProbeFailure File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1417 The HTTPS probe to 149.175.254.20 resulted in a redirect.
2/5/15 09:35:58.693 acvpnagent[22]: Function: analyzeHttpResponse File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1612 SG (149.175.254.20) contacted
2/5/15 09:35:58.693 acvpnagent[22]: Current network state: Secure Gateway accessible
2/5/15 09:35:58.697 acvpnagent[22]: Function: GetPrimaryInterfaceIndex File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 422 Unable to get global IPv6 information from system configuration.
2/5/15 09:35:58.697 acvpnagent[22]: Function: determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1769 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::FindDefaultRouteInterface Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
2/5/15 09:35:58.697 acvpnagent[22]: Function: updatePotentialPublicAddresses File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1914 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
2/5/15 09:35:58.814 CalendarAgent[242]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.coredav] [Refusing to parse response to PROPPATCH because of content-type: [text/html; charset=UTF-8].]
2/5/15 09:35:58.845 CalendarAgent[242]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.coredav] [Refusing to parse response to PROPPATCH because of content-type: [text/html; charset=UTF-8].]
2/5/15 09:35:58.958 CalendarAgent[242]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.coredav] [Refusing to parse response to PROPPATCH because of content-type: [text/html; charset=UTF-8].]
2/5/15 09:35:58.990 CalendarAgent[242]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.coredav] [Refusing to parse response to PROPPATCH because of content-type: [text/html; charset=UTF-8].]
2/5/15 09:36:11.402 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
2/5/15 09:36:14.600 sharingd[236]: 09:36:14.599 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
2/5/15 09:36:15.638 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
2/5/15 09:36:15.648 logind[71]: -[SessionManager getClient:withRole:inAuditSession:]:241: ERROR: No session dictionary for audit session 100079
2/5/15 09:36:15.648 logind[71]: _SMGetSessionAgent:73: ERROR: __SMGetClientForAuditSessionAgent failed 2
2/5/15 09:36:15.648 IMTransferAgent[3018]: SACShieldWindowShowing:925: ERROR: NULL response
2/5/15 09:36:15.859 com.apple.SecurityServer[58]: Session 100079 created
2/5/15 09:36:16.525 imagent[271]: [Warning] IMDFileTransferCenter: could not set kMDItemWhereFroms on file /var/folders/xz/zc4m4chn5pl5xbsn68xbdf31qzxhkh/T/073D299B-D9C5-4693-B58D-8E4101FC0B65/SubstandardFullSizeRender.jpg
2/5/15 09:36:16.525 imagent[271]: [Warning] IMDFileTransferCenter: could not set kMDItemWhereFroms on file /var/folders/xz/zc4m4chn5pl5xbsn68xbdf31qzxhkh/T/073D299B-D9C5-4693-B58D-8E4101FC0B65/SubstandardFullSizeRender.jpg
2/5/15 09:36:16.526 imagent[271]: [Warning] IMDFileTransferCenter: could not set kMDItemDownloadedDate on file /var/folders/xz/zc4m4chn5pl5xbsn68xbdf31qzxhkh/T/073D299B-D9C5-4693-B58D-8E4101FC0B65/SubstandardFullSizeRender.jpg
2/5/15 09:36:16.526 imagent[271]: [Warning] IMDFileTransferCenter: could not set kMDItemDownloadedDate on file /var/folders/xz/zc4m4chn5pl5xbsn68xbdf31qzxhkh/T/073D299B-D9C5-4693-B58D-8E4101FC0B65/SubstandardFullSizeRender.jpg
2/5/15 09:36:18.599 sharingd[236]: 09:36:18.599 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
```

Here is some more recent code, following wake attempt 08:46:25:

```
2/13/15 08:46:35.494 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
2/13/15 08:46:39.006 sharingd[234]: 08:46:39.005 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
2/13/15 08:46:43.002 sharingd[234]: 08:46:43.002 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
2/13/15 08:46:44.616 sharingd[234]: 08:46:44.616 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
```

Comment: You are not telling us the full story. You still have the Cisco AnyConnect VPN running "acvpnagent" that has a lots of problems. Also, how did your resolve the issue from your http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/169668/46541 ?

Comment: see this how to handle AnyConnect https://wiki.umms.med.umich.edu/display/UMHSHELPDESK/VPN+-+Cisco+AnyConnect+Client+for+Macintosh

Comment: What sort of computer is this? An iMac or MacBook* with a slow 5400RPM drive could easily take this long to wake into a fully functioning state, especially if it's waking a large number of processes. Most of the longer delays though seem to be network related. Using a slow VPN?

Comment: Thank you! I will look into AnyConnect VPN, which I rarely use. Login after sleep is not yet resolved, but at least some times it does seem to wake if i'm a bit patient. I was continually updating post on that thread due to space limitations and decided to start a new one.

Comment: Laptop is MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013), solid state drive. I hear you mention VPN as well, which is installed but not active...will look into that.

Comment: See more recent log at bottom of post above. I've also entirely uninstalled AnyConnect, btw.